# why does it shows error even though it seems to be quite appropriate?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int factors(int);

int main() {
   int n;
   cout<<"Enter a number: ";
   cin>>n;
   factors(n);
   return 0;
}

factors(int n){
    //To find out factors
    int i, arrA[5];
    arrA[0]=1;
    cout<<"Factors: ";
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
            if(n%j==0){
                arrA[i]=j;
            }
            else if(n%j!=0){
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int z=0;z < (sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(arrA[0]));z++){
        cout<<arrA[z]<<" ";
    }
}
```

This is a c++ code and for finding the factors of a given number.
But the problem is it's not producing the desired output.Problem is with the processing part(I think). It shows only "factors: " and continues to process and gives an error stating - "Untitled.exe has stopped working". Please fix the error and provide **an elaborate** explanation.

Comment: What is your input? do `arrA` have enough elements?

Comment: Hmmm, the program seems entering an infinite loop instead of stopping working with an input `4`.

Comment: You are missing the return type of `factors` in the function definition. Since this function does not return anything I suppose you change it to void.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the problem comes from the `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){` that contains `i--` which is a risk for infinite loop.

Since you tagged c++, do it with c++ this avoids a static array (arrA[5] is a good thing if you are sure there is only 5 factors but it depends on your n)

Instead use a std::list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
void factors(int n, std::list<int> & factors);

int main() {
   int n;
   cout<<"Enter a number: ";
   cin>>n;
   std::list<int> fact;

   factors(n, fact);

   cout<<"Factors: ";
   std::list<int>::iterator it=fact.begin();
   for(;it!=fact.end();it++)
   {
       std::cout << *it<<", ";
   }
   return 0;
}

void factors(int n, std::list<int> & factors)
{
    for(int j=2;j<=n;j++){
            if(n%j==0){
                factors.push_back(j);
            }
    }
}
```